Why does this Perl Regex one-liner not respect the \U escape sequence?
Why does this Perl Regex one-liner not make the full result upper case using the \U modifier?
I expect MY_NICE_WORD.
$ perl -pe 's/(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[A-Z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])/\U$1_$2\E/g' <(echo 'myNiceWord HTTPHeader')
my_Nice_Word HTTP_Header

According to the docs,
The following escape sequences are available in constructs that interpolate, but not in transliterations.

           \l          lowercase next character only
           \u          titlecase (not uppercase!) next character only
           \L          lowercase all characters till \E or end of string
           \U          uppercase all characters till \E or end of string
           \F          foldcase all characters till \E or end of string
           \Q          quote (disable) pattern metacharacters till \E or
                       end of string
           \E          end either case modification or quoted section
                       (whichever was last seen)

source: man --pager 'less -p "The following escape sequences are available in constructs that interpolate, but not in transliterations."' perlop
Isn't the replacement text within the context of interpolation?
Working Examples
When following the docs to my understanding, I can offer this working example:
$ perl -pe 's/(hello)/\U$1\E/g' <(echo hello)
HELLO

Regular Expression from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1176023/1236128
-> important case covered by this: HTTPHeader would not become h_t_t_p_header, rather HTTP_Header (or with upper case HTTP_HEADER)

Aren't all your matches zero-width? $1 and $2 are just empty strings

Yes, @muru. You're right! $1 and $2 are both empty. This explains why $ perl -pe 's/(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[A-Z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])/_/g' <(echo helloIAmACamel) yields hello_I_Am_A_Camel. I am confused why the replacement string can just be _. I would have expected the output to be 0 or more _ without the group matches.

What are you trying to do? We've now got two examples (rather than the original one) but no description of what you want to do

Chris Davies, please read my other comments. The question is clear, and the best answer is arguably @muru's (answers why X behavior happens), but this person left no answer. I extrapolated this comment and provided a more complete answer--armed with my new understanding that $1 and $2 are empty strings. Your downvote on my answer is unjustified (unless I really did extend the question in an answer--which I did not). Hope that helps.

Answer in Raku (a.k.a. Perl6) would be: raku -pe 's:g/ <?after <[a..z]>> <?before <[A..Z]>> | <?after <[A..Z]>+ > <?before <[A..Z]><[a..z]>> /_/; $_.=uc'. Given your test input, returns MY_NICE_WORD HTTP_HEADER.

"please read my other comments" - all the relevant details should be in the question. Comments can be missed or even deleted

You're using lookahead ((?=…)) and lookbehind ((<?=…)) assertions without anything to match and replace.
I think this is what you're trying to achieve, i.e. introduce an underscore in front of every capital letter and then capitalise the entire string:
perl -pe 's/([a-z]*)([A-Z][a-z]+)/\U$1_$2/g' <<<'myWord'
MY_WORD

perl -pe 's/([a-z]*)([A-Z][a-z]+)/\U$1_$2/g' <<<'myNiceWord'
MY_NICE_WORD

perl -pe 's/([a-z]*)([A-Z][a-z]+)/\U$1_$2/g' <<<'myReallyNiceWord'
MY_REALLY_NICE_WORD

but,
perl -pe 's/([a-z]*)([A-Z][a-z]+)/\U$1_$2/g' <<<'ReallyNiceWord'
_REALLY_NICE_WORD

So maybe
perl -pe 's/([a-z]*)([A-Z][a-z]+)/\U$1_$2/g; s/^_//' <<<'ReallyNiceWord'
REALLY_NICE_WORD

And if that's where you're going it's easier to split the "word" on capitals, join the components with _, and uppercase the result:
perl -pe '$_ = uc join("_", split(/(?=[A-Z])/) )' <<<'myReallyNiceWord'
MY_REALLY_NICE_WORD


Another, more streamlined approach if that's the intent: perl -pe 's/(?<=[a-z])([A-Z])/_$1/g; $_=uc'

@hobbs on that line, perl -pe '$_ = uc join("_", split(/(?=[A-Z])/) )'

Nice, that's smart :)

Hi @ChrisDavies, thanks. What I am trying to achieve and all of the subtle cases are described in reference to where I got the Regex inspiration from. e.g. HTTPHeader would not become "h_t_t_p_header", rather "HTTP_HEADER".

The "So maybe" example seems to handle both the undesired (1) initial underscore problem e.g. MyWord>MY_WORD and the (2) uppercase sequence problem e.g. HTTPHeader>HTTP_HEADER. The example afterwards "if that's where you're going" does not handle these cases (the s/^_// secondary pass seems to be the magic there)

@JonathanKomar I'm still guessing what you might want because you haven't told us (in English) what the requirement is

@ChrisDavies I think you are trying to hard to answer a question that I did not have. Reread the OP. The requirement has always been: Make the result upper case. All I changed in the OP since your answer was adding the HTTPHeader example, because it demonstrates that some of your answer is not equivalent to the regex in the OP.

@JonathanKomar I'm still puzzled because to make the string upper case is simply uc. There is something about underscores too, which I was guessing at, because it wasn't (and isn't) stated anywhere

@hobbs Most similar to ChrisDavies: perl -pe '$_ = uc join("_", split(/(?=[A-Z][a-z])/) )' but will fail on singly-initial-Cap words (will add underscore).

I accepted your answer, @ChrisDavies. No hard feelings. It is a good answer with some extras. I appreciate your time investment.

I see two issues: You are using zero-width assertions. I see no way of doing this in a single pass.
Will this work for you:
echo "unaffected Unaffected myNiceWord" |
  perl -pe 's/([a-z])([A-Z])/$1_$2/g; s/([a-zA-Z]*_[A-Z][a-z]*)/\U$1\E/g'

It fails on myFWord.

Yes, the original regular expression would convert HTTPHeader to HTTP_Header. The problem is that I would need it to be HTTP_HEADER. But honestly, @muru answered the precise question already in a comment. The rest is just icing on the cake.

This answer addresses the OP problem of making the result upper case / not being able to use \U on group captures when using 0-width matches (and continue using the same regular expression):
The answer is you can not use \U \E on group matchers of zero-width (?<=...) or (?=...) using $1 and $2, because they are not capture groups, rather look around operators  (Thanks Stéphane Chazelas)
A workaround for this limitation without changing the original expression is to postprocess the result like so:
Use the Perl special variable $_ to posprocess the output of the expression applied to a string: $_ = uc($_) whereby uc is a built-in uppercase function in Perl, converting the result to upper case.
perl -pe 's/(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[A-Z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])/\U$1_$2\E/g; $_ = uc($_)' <(echo 'myNiceWord HTTPHeader')
MY_NICE_WORD HTTP_HEADER

PS: muru's comment answered the question of why \U does not work, which was the motivation for my line of thinking in this answer. Thanks.

Aren't all your matches zero-width? $1 and $2 are just empty strings.


$1 and $2 are empty here, so it's the same as: perl -pe 's/(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[A-Z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])/_/g; $_ = uc($_)'

Please don't add an answer as an extension to the question. Instead, edit your question

It is not an extension to the question, rather an answer. No answer has suggested uc($_).  The question is the same and this is an answer on its own. And @muru answered the OP precisely, as stated. All other answers do not focus on the "English" question: "Why does this Perl Regex one-liner not respect the \U escape sequence?". Only Muru's comment did. No boogie problem to solve that you seem to be gunning at.

That answer is misleading, \U will uppercase whatever is after it, but here $1 and $2 are empty because there is no capture group in the pattern. Capture groups are (...). (?<=...) and (?=...) are look around operators, that's different operators from capture groups. If you added capture groups to what's matched inside those look-around operators, that would be wrong as those regexps match empty strings, so replacing those empty strings with the contents of capture groups (converted to upper case) would insert extra letters into the string.

s/.../.../ is short for $_ =~ s/.../.../. That is $_ is the variable s/.../.../ operates on by default. So you were already using (unknowingly) $_ before adding that $_ = uc $_

@StéphaneChazelas I updated the answer accordingly.
